# JQuery - randomly call slideUp and slideDown in chain

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code where I loop through img elements and want to randomly apply slideUp() and slideDown() jquery effects on them:

```
$c.each(function(){
    $(this).find('img:gt(0)').hide();

    setInterval(function () {           
        $(this).find(':first-child')
         .[sometimes slideUp(), sometimes slideDown()] // <<<
         .next('img')
         .fadeIn()
         .end()
         .appendTo(this)
     }.bind(this), 3000 + Math.random()*4000); // 4 seconds
});
```

I can't place functions in an array as they exist as element object methods. I also tried extending element object to add my properties, but it didn't work out well either and nor did a few other methods.

So, any ideas on how I can execute two different callbacks in turn or just randomly?

Comment: You might need to use the iterator in the `$.each()` and conditionally `slideUp()` or '`slideDown()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can reference properties using array syntax. So `["slideUp"]()` would call `.slideUp()`.

You can also extend this by putting a larger expression inside:

```
[ Math.random() > 0.5 ? "slideUp" : "slideDown" ]()
```

Comment: I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [`.

Comment: @showdev My mistake. I accidentally started the expression with `.[`. It shouldn't have the `.`